# PHPLot set y axis auto range to be fixed

Tags: php, phplot

I have this code to create graph using phplot:

```
$plot = new PHPlot();

//Define some data
$example_data = array(
     array('Learning',3),
     array('Reading',3),
     array('Writing',4),
     array('Oral Communication',2),
     array('Numeracy',2),
);
$plot->SetDataValues($example_data);
$plot->TuneYAutoRange(4, 'decimal');
$plot->SetYTickIncrement(1);
```

now this is the result:
[image]

as shown.. the y axis range is 0,1,2,3,4,5 .. is there anyway that I could set it into fixed range that the maximum y axis range is 4? the data of the graph is maximum of 4 only but when it get 4 value the graph y axis range will go to 5.

what I am looking for is a fixed range of 0,1,2,3,4 or I can say is maximum of 4 only.. I tried `$plot->TuneYAutoRange(0, 'R', 0);` but not working. do anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

It should be $plot->TuneYAutoRange(1, 'R', 0);